# Why the inlet and outlet fluxes are different when I solve the Poisson equation by FEM over a trapezoidal domain?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, finite-element-method, poissons-equation, finite-volume-method

I solved the Poission equation which is given by
\begin{equation}
\Delta h = 0,
\end{equation}
where $h$, in my case, is the hydraulic pressure. Because I want to solve steady-state flow, the $\nabla h =[\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial h}{\partial y}]$ is the flux velocity.

I used the FEATOOL in MATLAB to solve the Poisson equation over a trapezpodal domain, with three-noded triangular elements. The left and right sides are Dirichlet boundary conditions ($h_L = 100$ and $h_R = 20$), and the top and bottom sides are Neumann boundary condition ($\nabla h \cdot \vec{n} = 0$, $\vec{n}$ is the normal vector of boundary). The solved pressure field is as follows:
[pressure field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xI6V.jpg)

Then I wanted to determine the velocity of each element. Since the pressure value of each node is obtained, I used linear shape function $\vec{N}$ to get velocity:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \vec{N}^T}{\partial x}\vec{h_e} \text{ and } \frac{\partial h}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial \vec{N}^T}{\partial y}\vec{h_e},
\end{equation}
where $\vec {h_e}$ is the three pressure values of an element, $T$ denotes transpose. The derivates of $\vec{N}$ are
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \vec{N}}{\partial x} = \left(b_1, b_2, b_3\right)^T, b_i = \frac{1}{2A}(y_j - y_k),
\end{equation}
where $A$ is the area of an element, and
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \vec{N}}{\partial y} = \left(c_1, c_2, c_3\right)^T, c_i = \frac{1}{2A}(x_k - x_j).
\end{equation}

Using the above formulas, the velocity vectors are as follows:
[velocity vectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLfEH.jpg)

Finally, I used the $\nabla h \cdot \vec{n} \cdot L_\Gamma$ ($L_\Gamma$ is the length of boundary edge of an boundary element) to calculate the inlet and outlet flux. I found the difference is around 10% (inlet = 10.1017, outlet = 8.9828, error = 0.1108). Why this happened? Is it due to the length difference between inlet and outlet (I found when they are equal, the fluxes are equal)?

I also used quadratic elements, but the same problem happened when the domain is irregular, particularly the lengths of inlet and outlet are different.

**UPDATE**

With RT0 elements, the inlet and outlet fluxes are the same now! If you are interested, download a matlab script from [github](https://github.com/qq1012510777/mixed_FEM) (I just revised the original script a little and I still not very clear about mixed FEM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This finite element basis (3-noded triangular element) satisfies no discrete conservation properties. In particular, the conservation properties present in the continuous formulation $\Delta h = 0$ do not carry over to the discrete formulation. Moreover, the boundary flux has a quite low convergence rate, if I recall correctly it's $O(h^{1/2})$ for linear elements.

There are other more exotic finite elements and variational formulations that may better satisfy discrete conservation properties. Search for information, e.g., about $H(div)$ conforming finite elements.

Comment: hi, did you mean high order elements like quadratic element? i also tried this and got the same problem.

Comment: No, all of these elements are $H^1$ conforming and have the same problem. Instead you can try, for example, the mixed formulation of the Poisson problem and the Brezzi-Douglas-Marini element.

Comment: thanks! I see a lot of paper use RT0 element to solve the mixed formulation of the poisson equation. I will study that.